# How to insert values of variables dynamically in SQL Server Database using python script

Tags: python-3.x

Fist row in Data File:
1,Maria,Anders,Berlin,Germany,0300174321

```
f = open("Customer.csv", "r")

for row in f.readlines(i):

 a = row

 x = a.split(",")

 ID1 = print(x[0].replace("ï»¿",""))

 FIRST_NM1 = print(x[1])

 LAST_NM1 = print(x[2])

 CITY1 = print(x[3])

 COUNTRY1 = print(x[4])

 PHONE1 = print(x[5])

 cursor = cs.cursor()
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO sales.dbo.Customer_temp (ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,CITY,COUNTRY,PHONE) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(ID1,FIRST_NM1,LAST_NM1,CITY1,COUNTRY1,PHONE1))


cs.commit();
```

But it is inserting `None` in all rows so could you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the values you need to assign them;

```
FIRST_NM1 = x[1]

LAST_NM1 = x[2]

CITY1 = x[3]
```

etc..